# Tukey's IQR-method for outliers and highly skewed data

Tags: outliers, skewness

I am writing a thesis on performances on cognitive and linguistic measures. I have used the Tukey IQR method (Q1-1.5*IQR) to detect lower outliers in a non-normally distributed small sample of various cognitive and linguistic measures.

For one measure, data is highly skewed (-3.022) contrary to the other measures. Tukey's method identified more outliers for this specific measure than for the other measures. I find it unreasonable that all these outliers should reflect atypical performance within the context of my study rather than expected variation.

Therefore, I will argue why I will keep certain outliers. As I understand, whether to keep or not keep outliers is dependent on a study's purpose and context. One argument I am inclined to use is that Tukey's method may not be appropriate for small samples with highly skewed data.

Is it true, that although Tukey's method is appropriate for skewed data, it may over or underestimate outliers the more skewed the data is? That is my interpretation of (Seo, S., 2006).

*Seo, S. (2006). A Review and Comparison of Methods for Detecting Outliers in Univariate Data Sets. Master’s thesis, University of Pittsburgh.

Comment: This misrepresents what Tukey did and the advice he gave.  I recommend reading the introductory sections of his book *EDA* (Addison-Wesley 1977) because it will provide the arguments you seek.

Answer (score 0):

All statistical methods of identifying outliers are deeply flawed. They may be useful for showing you some points that you might *look* at, but they should never be used to automatically delete points.

Tukey was a genius, but his method, even for normal data, because it doesn't account for sample size. To be fair, Tukey probably never dealt with the humongous samples that we commonly get now. But if you have a sample of (say), 10,000, then you are going to get a bunch of points that are outliers by this definition.  E.g.

```
set.seed(1234) #Set a seed

x <- rnorm(10000) #Normal dist, mean 0, sd 1

#Get the IQR
quantile(x, c(.25, .75)) #-0.66 to 0.67
IQR <- 1.33
tukey <- 1.5*IQR

#Outliers via Tukey rule
sum(x > tukey) #There were 222
sum(x < -1*tukey) #205
```

Outliers should be removed when they are data entry errors. In nearly all other cases, you should use a method that allows for outliers.

An outlier is a surprising point. Only humans with knowledge of the variable can say what is surprising.  For instance, if you take the heights of 100 men from the general population, then getting someone over 2 meters tall is surprising.  If the sample is professional basketball players, it is not. And if you sample 10,000 from the general population, then it is not.

More generally, a lot of data analysts (I'm not saying the OP does this, but many do) try to do the analysis by "rule". You have to use your brains and your knowledge.

And, to once again quote Herman Friedman (my favorite professor in grad school): "If you're not surprised, you haven't learned anything".

Comment: Oooh.  You have my sympathy!  Supervisors who are untrained in statistics giving advice about statistics are a plague.

Comment: Tukey's EDA methods were primarily designed to be performed quickly by hand, on data sets that could be sorted (or at least binned) by hand; his definition of *practical power* in relation to the various *Quick tests* (power × probability of being used) makes it clear why - he wanted procedures people could and would use, in an era where computers were not widely available. Typically the largest sample sizes that this sort of hand-work is practical for is in the range of dozens (hundreds at best unless data are pre-sorted). Tukey didn't typically use these rules to exclude data, though.